# select from list by object type

Tags: c#

Structure of my project:

```
class Attachment { ... }
class Photo : Attachment { ... }
class Document : Attachment { ... }

class Page
{
    public List<Attachment> attachments;
                ...
}
```

I receive pages from the server:

```
List<Page> pages = ...load pages from server;
```

I need to get from this list pages which in the Attachments have only objects with type Photo.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var photos = attachments.OfType<Photo>();
```

If you instead want all pages with only photo-attachments:

```
var pagesWithPhotosOnly = pages.Where(p => p.attachments.All(pa => pa is Photo));
```

Answer (score 5):

One way of achieving this is iterating the list and checking the type of the `Attachment`.

```
var photos = attachments.Where(a => a is Photo);
```

Another method, as pointed in the comments and @TimSchmelter's answer, is to directly use the `OfType` extension method, which is arguably more "expressive" than using `Where`.

Comment: Another potential benefit of `OfType` instead of a `Where` like above is that `OfType` returns the items that are the type `as` the type (no additional casting required).

Comment: @crashmstr, point taken. If you'd need to access the member of the `Photo` objects after the filtering, `OfType` would be the way to go.